# Find all the primitive roots of $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all the primitive roots of $13$

**My attempt:**

Since that $13$ is a prime I need to look for $g$ such that $g^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$

There are $\phi(12)=4$ classes modulo $12$

how can I find the classes?

Comment: Try candidates until you find one, call it $g$. Then use the rule (valid in all finite groups): if the order of an element $g$ is $n$, then the order of the element $g^k$ is $n/\gcd(n,k)$.

Comment: All you have to do is find one primitive root $k$. Then take powers $k^a$ with $a$ relatively prime to $12$ to get the others.

Comment: So $2^5,2^7,2^{11}$ are primitive roots? @almagest

Comment: Correct: $2, 2^5,2^7,2^{11}$.

Comment: The question does not complete the definition of primitive root; it should also require that no smaller power $k$ has $g^k\equiv 1$

Comment: @Joffan: Alternatively, a number g with 12 different powers $g^1$ to $g^{12}$

Comment: @gnasher729 that works too, although "administratively" you'd need to check a lot of combinations (for larger $p$, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{13}$

as $2^n\not\equiv1\pmod{13}$ for $1\le n<12$

Now use ord$_ma=d, $ord$_m(a^k)=\dfrac{d}{(d,k)}$ ([Proof](http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862) @Page#95)

Here $d=\phi(13)=?$ and we need ord$_m(a^k)=d$ which needs $(d,k)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Take all the numbers less than and coprime to 13 . 1 to 12 are coprime to 13  . Check 
 $1^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$
 $2^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$
And so on upto 
 $12^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$
Every 1 to 12 which is $\equiv 1\pmod{13}$
 is the required answer .
$edit $: the power should be the least power which gives  the value  $\equiv 1\pmod{13}$

Comment: so the number one is also a primitive root?

Comment: @Error 404 No the least power which gives the value 1 is 1 itself so 1 is not a primitive root .

Comment: No, this is not the definition of a primitive root. The question does not complete the definition; it should also require that no smaller power $k$ has $g^k\equiv 1$

Comment: But you wrote $1^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ @Shona

Comment: @Error 404 i just edited the least value which gives the power of that number  $\equiv 1\pmod{13}$

Comment: @Joffan i corrected it

Answer (score 2):

My quick & dirty method was to note that $13-1=12$ has prime factors $2,3$ & quickly find squares and cubes of a numbers, since those cannot be primitive roots, and not checking those which have already turned up. Any indication  of a "short cycle" (like $5$) also gets discarded immediately.

$2: 2^2 \equiv 4, 2^3 \equiv 8 \\
3: 3^2 \equiv 9, 3^3 \equiv 1 \text{(discard all)}\\
5: 5^2 \equiv 12 \equiv -1 \text{(discard all)} \\
6: 6^2 \equiv 10, 6^3 \equiv 8 \\
7: 7^2 \equiv 10, 7^3 \equiv 5 \\
11: 11^2 \equiv 4, 11^3 \equiv 5 
$

leaving $\{2,6,7,11\}$ as the primitive roots which is in accordance with the expectation of $\phi(12)=4$ roots (and also the knowledge that for each primitive root $g \bmod p$, $-g$ is a primitive root iff $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$).

Answer (score 2):

Primes have not just one primitive root, but many. So you find the first primitive root by taking any number, calculating its powers until the result is 1, and if p = 13 you must have 12 different powers until the result is 1 to have a primitive root.

If you tried a number a that wasn't a primitive root then don't try it's powers but some other number.

Once you have one primitive root, call it g. $g^2$ is not a primitive root because $(g^2)^6 = g^{12} = 1$. Same for the powers 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10. $g^5$, $g^7$, $g^11$ are the other primitive roots.