# Need help with the proof of the following theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem: If $ord_{m}a=t$, then $ord_{m}a^n=t/(n,t)$

Proof: Let $(n,t)=d$. Then since $a^t \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$, we have

$$(a^t)^{n/d}=(a^n)^{t/d} \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$$,

so that if $ord_{m}a^n = t'$, then $$t'|t/d$$

But from the congruence  $$(a^n)^t{'} \equiv 1(mod \text{ } m)$$

We have $t|nt'$ by theorem 4-3, or

$$t/d|{n/d}t'$$

Since

$$(t/d,n/d)=1$$

we obtain $$t/d|t'$$

Combining $t'|t/d$ and $t/d|t'$ we have $t'=t/d$

why do we need n/d in the first statement and how does that show $t'|t/d$

Comment: See http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862  @Page#95. See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815832/find-all-the-primitive-roots-of-13

Answer (score 1):

The argument is essentiallyas follows (reorganized and presented bidirectionally)

$$ a^{nk}\equiv 1\iff t\mid nk\iff t\mid nk,tk\iff t\mid(nk,tk)=(n,t)k\iff t/(n,t)\mid k$$

The first $\iff$ follows because $\,t = {\rm\ ord}\, a,\,$ and the third follows by the [definition/universal property of the gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) and the [gcd distributive law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) You could also use lcm instead of gcd, i.e.

$\quad\ \ a^{nk}\equiv 1\iff t\mid nk\iff n,t\mid nk\iff [n,t]\mid nk\iff [n,t]/n\mid k$

Both are equivalent since $\ [n,t]/n = t/(n,t),\ $ i.e. $\ [n,t](n,t) = nt$.

**Remark** $\ $ Note that the first equivalence chain implies that $\,a^n\,$ has order $\,t/(n,t)\,$ since, generally, if $\  b^k = 1\iff j\mid k\ $ then this implies that $\,b\,$ has order $\,j.\,$ Indeed, setting $\,k=j\,$ implies $\,b^j=1\,$ and $\,j\,$ is the *least* postive $\,k\,$ with $\,b^k=1\,$ since $\,j\,$ divides all other such $\,k.\ $

Comment: Hi Bill Dubuque, I don't know why, but most of the times, it's so hard for me to follow your arguments. I still lack a lot of math background. I am just wondering why the $gcd(t/d,n/d)=1$

Comment: If $\,c>1\,$ and  $\,c\mid t/d,n/d\,$ then $\,cd\mid t,n,\,$ contra $\,d = (t,n)=\,$ *greatest* common divisor of $\,t,n.\, $ See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1213466/242)You are quite welcome to ask questions about things you find hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are using new notation because in mine $ord_m{a^n}=t'$. In yours, it is t. what is $t|nk,tk$?, are u saying that $t$ divides $nk$ and$ tk$?

Comment: No, same notation. The proof above shows that $\,a^{n\,k}=1\iff t_1\mid k,\,$ for $\,t_1 = t/(n,k).\,$ This implies $\,t_1 = {\rm ord}\, a^{n}\, (=: t')$ since for $\,k=t'$ it implies $\,t_1\mid t'.\,$ Conversely for $\,k=t_1\,$ it implies $\,(a^n)^{t_1} = 1\,$ so $\,t'\mid t_1.\,$ Thus $\,t_1\mid t'\mid t_1\,$ so $\,t' = t_1.\ $ That $\iff$ is a very handy characterization of "order".

Comment: @TheMathNoob Some of your difficulties may be from proceeding too fast. Be sure you have properly understood things before moving forward.